# How to get the Labels for my Forest Plot to Appear using the op function?

Tags: r, plot

I was successful in creating a forest plot for my study. However, the labels at the top of the forest plot (i.e., title of the columns) are not showing up on my forest plot. I am using the `op<- par (cex = 1, font = 2)` function below. They are successfully being "run" as evidenced by my console. However, the labels are not showing up. I've used these exact coordinates on a prior forest plot as labels which have worked perfectly. Why am I not able to get it to show up using this function and what can I do to fix it? Or where can I find the information (i.e., package or website?).

```
author<-as.character(na.omit(data.1$Author)) 

tx<-as.character(na.omit(data.1$treat1))

forest(FTmet.3,
       xlim = c(-14,6),
       at = c(-3, 0,.75, 3),
       slab = paste(author),
       ilab = cbind(tx),  
       ilab.xpos = c(-6), cex = 1)

op <- par(cex = 1, font = 2)
      text(-13.2,20.5, "Study")
      text(-6.2, 20.5, "Intervention")
      text(3.5, 20.5, "Standardized Mean Difference (g)")
```